# Ruby huge Hash & memory usage

Tags: ruby, memory, hash

How to improve memory usage ?

I do a translator, from English to 10 languages.

Ex:  `TRANSLATION_HASH["dog"]["fr"] => chien.`

TRANSLATION_HASH contains 10 000 000 English expressions.

It works great, but takes 10Gb of memory....
Note: TRANSLATION_HASH is read only (i never  write to it)

All is loaded (10 000 000 english expressions X 10 translations) once at start:

`TRANSLATION_HASH["word 1"]["fr"] = "french word from word 1"
 TRANSLATION_HASH["word 1"]["es"] = "Spanish word from word 1"
 TRANSLATION_HASH["word 1"]["de"] = "German word from word 1`

Comment: How does your translator work? Do you need all 10 languages at once?

Comment: Do you need to load all 10 languages at once?

Comment: Yes, i load all 10 languages at once in environment.rb (it takes 20 min.....)

Comment: Did you consider storing the translations into a database instead of a hash in memory?

Comment: Storing translations into a external database is not an option because it would be much too slow. Hash read access is much faster that DB access.

Comment: @JoJo so you load all languages upon startup, but do you actually need all of them at any time? Maybe you could load them lazily, i.e. as needed.

Comment: _"external database is not an option because it would be much too slow"_ – what about an in-memory database like Redis?

Comment: @Stephan, 
=> yes, all langages loaded at once at start.
=> Redis is much slower that direct access in ruby Hash....Not an option

Comment: You could implement a cache which keeps the most common (or recently used) words in memory (say the top 1%) and fetches less common words from a slower source (database or disk).

Comment: I tend to get skeptical when I hear protests of "that would be too slow!" No where do you say how fast it needs to be. Without performance targets improvement is difficult. Further, I'd wager that at 10 Gigs, your hash implementation is being slowed down a lot by system paging,  I once worked on a project where the original design kept all data in hashes. It was very slow. The version that used a database was actually faster!

Answer (score 1):

You should familiarize yourself with how the `Hash` is stored in the memory. There's a good blog post about that [here](https://anadea.info/blog/how-hash-table-works-ruby-examples).

If your dictionary contained only words instead of phrases, you should just have about 90mb of data per language (assuming 4 bytes for reference and 5 characters average word length), meaning about 1gb of data in total, the way hashes and strings work will require a great deal more memory than that, each string is an object that holds information such as the memory location, character encoding, length and so on. So ten times the memory consumption of the plain text data is actually a quite good accomplishment from Ruby.

As others have suggested, the best option would be to store this data in a database or key-value store such as Redis, but you have rejected that option because of performance issues (on a regular laptop, Redis can perform well over 500 000 GETs per second).

Another option to reduce the memory consumption would be to reduce the use of hashes and rely on array indexes. Your translator could look like this:

```
TRANSLATIONS = { 
  "hello" => ['bonjour', 'hola'],
  "thanks" => ['merci', 'gracias']
}

LANGUAGES = { french: 0, spanish: 1 }

def translate(english_word, language)
  TRANSLATIONS.dig(english_word, LANGUAGES[language])
end

translate('hello', :spanish)
 => 'hola'
```

Also, I can't resist noting that a translator made in this manner does not produce a result that is useful in any context. You can't translate sufficiently just by replacing each word with a translation of the word from another language. Also you would have to store pairs for each grammatical case, "sleep, sleeps, sleeping, slept, sleeper, sleepy, asleep, ..." to even find a matching word.

Also, the Oxford English Dictionary only contains 171 476 words.

Comment: Thank you Kimmo. I ll benchmark Redis again and share results. Such a translator is usefull if not to be used by human, and offer great throughput. – JoJo just now

Comment: In Dev env, TRANSLATIONS contains "only" 3 400 000 elements.    `Benchmark.measure {TRANSLATIONS.each do |key, value| {redis.get(key)}}
994 sec

Benchmark.measure {TRANSLATIONS.each do |key, value| {TRANSLATIONS[key]}}
1.2 sec`

Comment: Kimmo, finally, Redis is a good solution, as i can balance load among many threads.

Answer (score 0):

After the following changes took places, it took less memory, and was faster:

TRANSLATION_HASH was a Hash of hash ( 10 000 000 of hashes stored in a Hash)
The index (ex: "dog") was a string

Ex: TRANSLATION_HASH["dog"]["fr"] => "chien".

Changed:
TRANSLATION_INDEX["dog"] => 1169    //hash storing a uniq key for each  10 000 000 English expressions.
TRANSLATION_FR[1169] => "chien"
TRANSLATION_ES[1169] => "perro"
...

So,  I turned 10 000 000 hashes into 11, and work with int index.